# why do avr fuses need to be set when avr recognises crystal automatically

Tags: avr

Today I had trouble getting my programmer to recognise my avr. The reason was because the sck period was incorrect for the internal oscillator. As soon as I fitted a crystal it worked fine.

I'm confused as to why do we bother setting the avr fuses for the crystals if it can recognise the crystal anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that the crystal was used? The internal oscillator might have be tuned a bit because of the attached Crystal, or the fuses were already set for the crystal. It would be totally new to me that the AVRs autodetect a clock source. There are too many ways this could go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to generate a clock signal in a microcontroller.  You need the fuses in order to tell the microcontroller how to generate or find that clock signal.  The microcontroller cannot automagically detect the clock.

It may well be that your microcontroller defaulted to using a crystal with the right settings for the type of crystal you attached.

I am not certain about the Atmels, but here's some PIC setting types:

- Three groupings of oscillators: Internal, External crystal, External clock
- Crystal can be High Speed (>4MHz), eXtra high Speed (>16MHz), Normal speed [EC] (<4MHz) and Low Power (32.768KHz).  Different electronics are required to handle the different speeds.
- The external clock setting requires a clock input on only one pin.  This *has* to be set in fuses or it just won't work.
- The internal clock signal could be generated in various ways - RC, crystal, etc.  Again, the µC needs telling how to do it.

You can also tell the µC to use (one or both of) its oscillator pins as IO pins.  Again, this is coupled with the oscillator fuses, so has to be set there.

Personally I do think that fuses for this kind of thing are a silly idea, and the clock signal could very well default to the internal oscillator on power up and then the firmware select another (faster, more stable, lower power, etc) clock signal to operate from without needing to faff around with fuses.

Comment: A reason for having fuses is if it always powered up in RC mode, it would need to be the lowest power, slowest mode, to support use on power sources with  very low current capability. This would cause startup delays which may be unacceptable for other applications.

Comment: This is true - good point.

Answer (score 0):

More often, it is because that you want a more stable clock source. The on-chip oscillator in AVR is not very accurate and has some jitter. We need external oscillator also because the the frequency of on-chip oscillator, when divided by whole numbers, cannot generate the standard baud rates for U(S)ART communication.